# Xamarin: Exceptions raised from tasks are not propagated

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, async-await

I have the following code in Xamarin (tested in ios):

```
private static async Task<string> TaskWithException()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
        throw new Exception ("Booo!");
        return "";
    });
}

public static async Task<string> RunTask()
{
    try
    {
        return await TaskWithException ();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Invoking this as `await RunTask()`, does throw the exception from the `TaskWithException` method, but the catch method in `RunTask` is never hit. Why is that? I would expect the catch to work just like in Microsoft's implementation of async/await. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you use `.Result`, `Wait` or `WaitAll` anywhere in your code, directly or indirectly referencing the task returned by `RunTask`?

Comment: This works as expected in a console app in VS2013.

Comment: The code was being called from the constructor of a Xamarin Forms View. I didn't think that detail was relevant, but it looks like starting a task like this from the constructor does not fire the exception handler.

Comment: any updates on that? struggling with the same?

Comment: any updates? I can't debug my ios app...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant `await` a method inside of a `constructor`, so thats why you can't catch the `Exception`.

To catch the `Exception` you must `await` the operation.

I have here two ways of calling an async method from the constructor:

**1.** `ContinueWith` solution

```
RunTask().ContinueWith((result) =>
{
    if (result.IsFaulted)
    {
        var exp = result.Exception;
    }      
});
```

**2.** Xamarin Forms

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await RunTask();    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString());
    }    
});
```

**3.** iOS

```
InvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        await RunTask();    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString());
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to this old question. From what I remember, we used #2 to resolve the problem at that time. Shame on me for not following through and answering my own question! :(